# Issues getting jQuery cycle to run multiple instances on one page

Tags: jquery, cycle

I started a topic a while ago about getting multiple instances of the jQuery cycle plugin to run on one page, each using an individual set of controls. Link: [Need multiple jQuery cycle sliders to use different prev/next buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296221/need-multiple-jquery-cycle-sliders-to-use-different-prev-next-buttons)

I got a response that seemed like the right idea, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm still learning javascript and sometimes struggle with getting things in the right place, but I tried adding the code that was given to me everywhere I could think of, and nothing worked. This was my original script:

```
$('.slides').cycle({ 
        fx:      'scrollHorz', 
        speed:  'slow', 
        timeout: 0, 
        nowrap: true,
        pause:   1,
        prev: $('.slider-arrow-left'),
        next: $('.slider-arrow-right'),
        cssBefore:{ 
            top: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            display: 'block'
        }, 
        animOut: {  
            top: 360
        },
        before: function(curr, next, opts){
            var $curr = $(curr);
            var $next = $(next);
        },
        pause: 1,
        pager: '.slider-controls',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
            return '.slider-controls li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
        }
    });
```

The solution code that was provided:

```
$('.slides').each(function(){
     /* look for controls only within this instance*/
        var nextBtn=$(this).parent().find('.slider-arrow-left');
            $(this).cycle({ 
            next: nextBtn
        });
        var prevBtn=$(this).parent().find('.slider-arrow-right');
            $(this).cycle({ 
            prev: prevBtn
        });
    });
```

Is this correct code? If so, can someone give me the complete code? My basic HTML layout is this (complete code repeated 4 times on page):

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
        Images
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        Images
    </div>

</div>
<img src="images/arrow-L.png" alt="Left" class="slider-arrow-left"/>
<img src="images/arrow-R.png" alt="Right" class="slider-arrow-right"/>
</div><!--slider-->
```

Comment: Any chance you could create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show what you actually have?

Comment: Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gbYhB/9/
For some reason it's working a little differently than the live site, on the live site no matter which set of arrows you click, it only controls the first slider. I also had trouble getting the Left arrow to show up on the fiddle, but you can see that the Right arrow moves all the sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand your problem now.

To start off, to have the arrow to show I needed to set it's styling to `left: 0;` since that's as far as you can go in the fiddle.

Secondly to have more than one "cycle" plugin in one page you need to assign different names to them and different names to their arrow attributes otherwise they will all control the same thing. Not sure that you need so many properties but decided not to tinker with that.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gugahoi/gbYhB/12/

And the major changes are:

**HTML**

```
<h3>Website Design</h3>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slides" id="cycleOne">  <!-- Added ID -->
...
...
    <img src=".../arrow-L.png" alt="Left" class="slider-arrow-left move-left"/> <!-- Added class 'move-left' to target with jquery-->
    <img src=".../arrow-R.png" alt="Right" class="slider-arrow-right move-right"/> <!-- Added class 'move-right' to target with jquery-->
</div><!--slider-->
<h3>Print Design</h3>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slides" id="cycleTwo">  <!-- Added ID -->
    ...
    ...
    <img src=".../arrow-L.png" alt="Left" class="slider-arrow-left move-left2"/> <!-- Added class 'move-left2' to target with jquery-->
    <img src=".../arrow-R.png" alt="Right" class="slider-arrow-right move-right2"/>  <!-- Added class 'move-right2' to target with jquery-->
</div><!--slider-->
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#cycleOne').cycle({  // id of first cycle
    ...
    prev: $('.move-left'),  // Targeting classes for the first set of arrows
    next: $('.move-right'), // to control the first cycling
    ...
});
$('#cycleTwo').cycle({  // id of second cycle
    ...
    prev: $('.move-left2'), // Targeting classes for the second set of arrows
    next: $('.move-right2'),// to control the second cycling
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.slides').each(function(){
    /* look for controls only within this instance*/
    $(this).cycle({ 
        fx:      'scrollHorz', 
        speed:  'slow', 
        timeout: 0, 
        nowrap: true,
        pause:   1,
        prev: $(this).parent().find('.sl_prev'),
        next: $(this).parent().find('.sl_next'),
    });
});
```