# How to create a JQuery slider from scratch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, customization, jquery-effects

See image:

[image]

I am new to JQuery and a bit confused as to how to go about this.  Basically, I want to have left and right buttons where the user can navigate through those 4 slides and then the dots at the bottom should be clickable taking the user to the slide (dot) they click on.

How do I do this?

Comment: this answer might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608356/how-to-build-simple-jquery-image-slider-with-sliding-or-opacity-effect). Try replacing img with a div container or an actual text.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to learn to do this yourself then i suggest you sign up for a tutorial site like http://tutsplus.com, they have great learning programs for only $20 a month.
There is a course called 30 days to learn jQuery which covers how to make a slider. Here is a link for that: http://learnjquery.tutsplus.com/
Just a side note, this course they offer for free, but once you watch the videos and see the quality of instruction you will see it is worth the money to sign up for membership.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for that

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Here is the demo

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Please do note there a lot of libraries like these and this is just one of them .