# Slider two div at the same time left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, effect

I want to hide/ show div both at the same time but the effect does not work immediately.

Here is my code :

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var div_hide = $(this).parent();
    var div_show = $(this).attr('href');
    $(div_hide).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    $(div_show).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800); //Doesn't work
    //$(div_show).delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800); //Work but i must waiting...
});
```

Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e3tAZ/

Do you have an alternative solution maybe ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build simple jQuery image slider with sliding or opacity effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608356/how-to-build-simple-jquery-image-slider-with-sliding-or-opacity-effect)

Answer (score 1):

Set `queue` to false

```
$(div_hide).hide({ direction: "left", queue: false, duraton: 500 });
$(div_show).show({ direction: "right", queue: false, duraton: 500 });
```

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nZrv/)