# Dynamically Adding jquery sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, slider, bjqs

I have a site that will display multiple slider slideshow images based upon category drop down menus.  My first time using Jquery and I am having trouble getting more than one to show correctly. I'm using the bjqs basic jquery slider code.

aspx:

' alt="no image" width="940" height="450" title='<%# Eval("txtJobName") %>' />

Jquery:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#slideshow0').bjqs({
        'width': 940,
        'height': 450,
        'automatic': false,
        'showcontrols': true,
        'centercontrols': true, // center controls verically
        'nexttext': 'Next', // Text for 'next' button (can use HTML)
        'prevtext': 'Prev', // Text for 'previous' button (can use HTML)
        'showmarkers': true, // Show individual slide markers
        'centermarkers': true, // Center markers horizontally
        'responsive': true,
        'usecaptions': true
    });
});

Can someone tell me what I'm missing my results are coming out strange..as if the slider is not completely seperate. The first set of prev/next/number buttons don't work and the second set will show the first 3 images at the top and the rest at the bottom of the screen.  unfortunately, I am unable to send screenshot.

Thank you!

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608356/how-to-build-simple-jquery-image-slider-with-sliding-or-opacity-effect/12608357#12608357

Comment: Thanks, I think that's a great get started example.  I'm not having any problems if there is only one slider but my issue comes up when I am dynamically adding more.