# create image slider like youtube channel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, slider

i was wondering how can i create image slider like YouTube channel. when there is many video on a channel YouTube put them in a slider and we have back and forth button to see other video which doesn't show on the page and when we click on this back or forth button which are on different side of screen image start to move to left or right. two properties are important to me. 1. image slide from left to right or vise versa and 2. i can click on those image and go to another page.i mean image become clickable. i search image slider in Google but all i'v got was those image slider which we put under the banner for showcase. i don't know if the real name of this method is image slider. please give me a post or URL tutorial or even a YouTube video about create this kind of stuff. tank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called an image slider.
Where do you want to use it? If you want to create your own, this question might help you: [How to build simple jQuery image slider with sliding or opacity effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608356/how-to-build-simple-jquery-image-slider-with-sliding-or-opacity-effect)

Have a look at this page for a multi-image-at-once slider implementation: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified

Have a look at this website for a showcase of the different types of sliders available: http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. it was more than i needed.