# Image Slider Development

Tags: javascript, slider, scriptaculous

I am learning Image Slider Development. I am trying to develop an Image Slider like [this](http://slidervilla.com/placid/) one. I am using Scriptaculous. I placed images using `img` tag. In this regard, I can move images from right to left. But how can I reproduce the images at right side?? How can I make a cycling circle ?? How can I iterate images like they are adjacent to each other ??

Could anyone help me to get an Idea regarding this??

Answer (score -1):

There are alot of really good places to start I would recommend [How to build simple jQuery image slider with sliding or opacity effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608356/how-to-build-simple-jquery-image-slider-with-sliding-or-opacity-effect). You may not need the opacity but it covers good information.

Comment: Thanks @MaXiNom for your reply. Actually I am looking for Idea How to develop Image Scroller.